# Parsing Error in Developer Console (happens on run on Chrome as well, but only when launched via Pupppeteer)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

When trying to scrape linkedin search results via puppetteer, i noticed that the search results page shows a blank. Upon investigation, i noticed in the developer console inside chromium launched by puppeteer this error:

```
Error while processing route: search.results.people Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at u.s._deserializeQueryParam (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/br/6n33815bd6sdo077qodh7watx:3028:140)
    ....
6n33815bd6sdo077qodh7watx:3028 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at u.s._deserializeQueryParam (6n33815bd6sdo077qodh7watx:3028)
    ....
```

This error does not occur if I launch chromium manually and load the  same search URL.

This is preventing the search results from loading

Any ideas?

FYI Video that explains this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYhrDWLJJ9o

#### Steps to reproduce

**Tell us about your environment:**

- Puppeteer version: latest (v4.0.0)
- Platform / OS version: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- URLs (if applicable): Searching linkedin (here's an example [url](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetGeoRegion=%5B%22us%3A296%22%5D&keywords=dwayne&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER)) - you need to login to your linkedin account to set the cookies
- Node.js version: v13.13.0 . NPM version 6.14.4

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

```
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          "ignoreHTTPSErrors": true,
          "headless" : false,
          "args" :[
            '--ignore-certificate-errors',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--start-maximized',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            `--window-size=1200,800`,
            '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36',
    ]});

    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({"width": c["width"],"height": c["height"]});
    await page.setUserAgent(c["user_agent"]);    

    await page.goto(c["url"])
```

(where c["url"] is the link above)

The developer console on chromium has thjis output, which affects the page from rendering anything:

```
Error while processing route: search.results.people Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at u.s._deserializeQueryParam (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/br/6n33815bd6sdo077qodh7watx:3028:140)
    ....
6n33815bd6sdo077qodh7watx:3028 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at u.s._deserializeQueryParam (6n33815bd6sdo077qodh7watx:3028)
    ....
```

I tried upgrading chromium to latest. Nothing

Also tried on chrome by setting executablePath. Oddly enough, this error only shows up when going through puppeteer but not when I manually launch browser and go to the same URL.

**What is the expected result?**
Expected output doesn't show at all. Expected page an be seen if you just manually open browser and go to the URL as specified above.

**What happens instead?**

Page shows no search results.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about how to violate the LinkedIn terms of service rather than a generic software development question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it doesn't like how that parameter is escaped.

https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetGeoRegion=%5B%22us%3A296%22%5D&keywords=dwayne&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER

should be:

https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetGeoRegion=["us:296"]&keywords=dwayne&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER